# Automatic column width in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, formatting

In Word 2010, there is an "AutoFit" feature for table columns, that makes the column automatically be an appropriate width for its contents. How do I get the same in Excel?

I can double click on the column border to automatically set width to *current contents*. More efficiently, I can `Ctrl+A` twice to select all cells, then double click any divider, which will automatically expand all columns.

But any time I alter the contents of my cells, the size does not get re-adjusted. If I type a lot of text in a cell, the column will not stretch on its own, and if I delete some long text it will not shrink. I have do the select all, autofit width thing over and over again.

I want the columns to just snap to an appropriate width automatically. Is this possible in Excel 2010 or later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable Macros:

```
Press Alt + 11
```

Right click on the workbook you wanted to be autofit, then select work book on the first dropdown menu in the editor window and Sheet change in the second drop down.

Now write this inside the new function:

```
Columns().AutoFit
```

So your code should look something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  Columns().AutoFit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Automatic Method:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _ 
 ByVal Target As Range) 
 Dim actCol, curCol 
 actCol = Target.Column 
 If actCol > 52 Then 
 curCol = Chr(Int((actCol - 1) / 52) + 64) & _ 
 Chr(Int((actCol - 27) / 26) + 64) & _ 
 Chr(Int((actCol - 27) Mod 26) + 65) 
 ElseIf actCol > 26 Then 
 curCol = Chr(Int((actCol - 1) / 26) + 64) & _ 
 Chr(Int((actCol - 1) Mod 26) + 65) 
 Else 
 curCol = Chr(actCol + 64) 
 End If 
 Columns(curCol & ":" & curCol).AutoFit 
 End Sub
```

1. Copy the above code
2. With your workbook open, press ALT + F11 (Function Key F11)
3. Double click 'THIS WORKBOOK' in the Microsoft Excel VBA Project objects in the upper left quadrant.
4. Paste the event handler into the white editing area to the right (right click inside the area and 'Paste').
5. Close the VBE (red button w/white 'x' --- top right).
6. Save the workbook.
7. Enter data in any column, in any sheet in the workbook, and if it exceeds the column width the column will autofit once you select a cell in a different column.

Found this info [here](https://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130122181628AAJfAJa)

**Alternative Method: (Not Automatic)**

1.Select the column or columns that you want to change.

2.On the Home tab, in the Cells group, click Format.

The Cells group on the Home tab

3.Under Cell Size, click AutoFit Column Width.

[image]

[Microsoft KB link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-column-width-and-row-height-515116a6-ca55-4bdf-abe9-363e53e0ff0a#__toc248310479)

Comment: Sorry this method doesn't snap and needs to be re-applied after entering new data. I see your dilemma now. digging more

Comment: @Hari's answer is the cleaner better approach :) Nicely done.